# Sketching the image of a given function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the upper half-plane $\cal H$ and the map $$\varphi:\cal H\rightarrow\mathbb{C},~z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}.$$

Can somebody sketch the image $\varphi(S)$ with $$S=\{z\in{\cal H}:|\text{Re}(z)|<1/2,~ |z|>1\}?$$

I know that the image is included in the unit disk. And I guess that the boundary is some kind of triangle. Does this 'triangle' touches the boundary of the unit disk? Where is the point $i\infty$ maped to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the unit circle containing region $\varphi(S)$ which is the interior of the "triangle";

- The vertical line segment $[i(-2+\sqrt{3}),i(2-\sqrt{3})]$ is the image of the arc of circle.
- The circle arcs are the images of vertical boundaries. Due to the fact that $\varphi(z)$ can be written under the form $\dfrac{1-\frac{i}{z}}{1+\frac{i}{z}}$, $\varphi(i\infty)$ is clearly $1$.

Remark 1: $S$ is known to be a fundamental region for the action of a $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{C}$ on $H$ (the upper plane Poincaré space) and is pictured [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group)

Remark 2: for a proof that $\varphi(S)$ is like that, see the answer by @David Quinn.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Have you drawn this with TikZ? May you post the code please?

Comment: No, I have done it with Mathematica, and my ugly code wouldn't help you a lot. I think that it can easily be redrawn now, knowing that the circular arcs have their centers in $(1,\pm2)$ and radius $2$, start in $(1,0)$ and end up in $(0,\pm(2-\sqrt{3}))$. If I had to draw it, I would use Geogebra (that can hopefully generate TikZ output)

Comment: Given the set $S$ can Mathematica draw the image under $\varphi$? And can Mathematica in general draw fundamental domains?

Comment: Yes, of course, but not with a single command. Dealing with the parametrization of non bounded straight lines like the ones issued from $(\pm1,\sqrt{3}/2)$ has been done in an approximate manner. I think that a Mathematica program giving in a "clean" way the image of any triangle in $\frak H$ can be written, rather easily for a triangle with no point at infinity, and with a little care i one wants to cope with the special case of non bounded lines under the condition to handle properly the special case of non-bounded lines.

Answer (score 1):

This being a Mobius transformation, $\varphi$ maps straight lines or circles to straight lines or circles.  A straight line or circle is determined by $3$ points, so take three points on it, find their images, and see what is the straight line or circle through those points.

If $z$ is real, $z - i = \overline{z+i}$, so $\varphi(z) = 1$.  Thus $\varphi$ maps the real line to the unit circle.  So it's not true that the image is in the unit circle.  The upper half plane maps into the unit circle, the lower half plane outside.

Comment: But $S$ is in the upper half-plane, so the image is in the unit circle. Or what do I get wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow missed the $z \in \mathcal H$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$w=u+iv=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$

Rearranging, we have $$z=i\left(\frac{1+w}{1-w}\right)$$

The region $S$ is defined by three conditions.

Firstly, $|z|>1\implies|1+w|>|1-w|\implies u>0$

Now when $z$ is expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$ and simplified, we get $$z=\frac{i(1-u^2-v^2)-2v}{(1-u)^2+v^2}$$

So applying the second condition, that $Im(z)>0$ leads to the inequality $$u^2+v^2<1$$

Finally we also have $Re(z)<\frac 12$ and this leads to the inequality $$(u-1)^2+(v+2)^2>4$$

So the required region lies to the right of the imaginary axis, inside the unit circle and outside the circle whose centre is $(1,-2)$ with radius $2$.

Comment: There is a third condition : $\Re(z)>-\dfrac{1}{2}$ which gives the exterior of another circle (see my figure).

Comment: @David Quinn Thanks!